# Problems installing Haskell's plugins package (Windows 8.1 64-bit, cygwin)

Tags: haskell, installation, package

I can't get this package to install. I've tried outside of cygwin, and get this error:

http://pastebin.com/tcEsFXVT

I've tried inside cygwin, and get this error:

http://pastebin.com/LHGDnnDb

I tried downloading the latest config.guess and config.sub, putting them into the plugins local repository (.tar.gz), and installing from it:

http://pastebin.com/txbW9G9t

I even tried doing the same with only config.guess:

http://pastebin.com/yVQhgyKs

Based on Reid Barton's suggestion, I tried converting config.guess and config.sub to Unix line-endings (totally forgot about that issue, so thanks!). This produced a fifth error (replacing only config.guess did not change the error):

http://pastebin.com/U5rS6CyD

Can anyone provide instructions for how to install this bear?

Comment: I don't understand the third error, but the last one looks like a Windows line ending issue. Probably your config.guess has \r\n line endings while sh is expecting \n line endings.

Comment: The last error you get is `lexical error in string/character literal at character 'P'`. The code you have simply does not compile (it doesn't even parse). You have a recent compiler and this package hasn't been updated in two years, so really this is to be expected. At this point you can try to fix it yourself or contact the maintainer.

Comment: The offending line is `ghcLibraryPath  = GHC_LIB_PATH` so I guess `GHC_LIB_PATH` is set to something like `"C:\Program Files\..."`... and `\P` is not an escape sequence. Probably it would not work correctly on a UNIX system either when the path contains a backslash.